# PHPUnit testing with closures

Tags: php, phpunit, closures

This came up trying to write a test for a method of a class that calls a mock method with a closure.  How would you verify the closure being called?

I know that you would be able to assert that the parameter is an instance of `Closure`. But how would you check anything about the closure?

For example how would you verify the function that is passed:

```
 class SUT {
     public function foo($bar) {
         $someFunction = function() { echo "I am an anonymous function"; };
         $bar->baz($someFunction);
     }
 }

 class SUTTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
     public function testFoo() {
         $mockBar = $this->getMockBuilder('Bar')
              ->setMethods(array('baz'))
              ->getMock();
         $mockBar->expects($this->once())
              ->method('baz')
              ->with( /** WHAT WOULD I ASSERT HERE? **/);

         $sut = new SUT();

         $sut->foo($mockBar);
     }
 }
```

You can't compare two closures in PHP.  Is there a way in PHPUnit to execute the parameter passed in or in some way verify it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't injecting your dependency (the closure), which always makes unit testing harder, and can make isolation impossible.

Inject the closure into `SUT::foo()` instead of creating it inside there and you'll find testing much easier.

Here is how I would design the method (bearing in mind that I know nothing about your real code, so this may or may not be practical for you):

```
class SUT 
{
    public function foo($bar, $someFunction) 
    {
        $bar->baz($someFunction);
    }
}

class SUTTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    public function testFoo() 
    {
        $someFunction = function() {};

        $mockBar = $this->getMockBuilder('Bar')
             ->setMethods(array('baz'))
             ->getMock();
        $mockBar->expects($this->once())
             ->method('baz')
             ->with($someFunction);

        $sut = new SUT();

        $sut->foo($mockBar, $someFunction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you suggest we do something like `$someFunction = function() { echo "I am an anonymous function"; }; $sut = new SUT(); $sut->foo($bar, $someFunction);`. How do we test it there? My point is, the anonymous function has to be defined *somewhere*. You can pass it up the call stack all you want, but eventually it has to be defined. So how do you test it?

Comment: @Travesty3:  My answer contained the rewritten test showing you exactly how to test it.  You test it just like you would anything else that uses injected dependencies - you mock the dependency and inject the mock.

Comment: @Travesty3 You can have a factory class that returns the closures then you would be able to test the logic of the closure in isolation

Comment: @drrcknlsn: You're showing how to test the `SUT::foo()` method with the anonymous function mocked, but not how to test **the anonymous function**. What I mean is, how do you verify that "I am an anonymous function" gets echoed?

Comment: @Travesty3: The job of `SUTTest::testFoo()` is to verify that `SUT::foo()` behaves as expected.  According to your pasted code, `SUT::foo()`'s only job is to call the function.  The test in my answer verifies that the function is called, and so it has verified that `SUT::foo()` behaves as expected.  If you need to test the function itself, then you can do so in another test suite dedicated to doing so.  Provide it known good/bad inputs and verify the outputs (or side effects, as relevant).

Comment: @drrcknlsn: My colleague, Schleis, informs me that I may have come off in an attacking manner. Sorry if that was the case. I was trying to improve your answer. It was not obvious to me that you could test the anonymous function by creating it with a factory and then testing the factory's returned callback. I think that should be explained in your answer.

Comment: @Travesty3: Well, I'm skeptical about the need to test the closure itself, anyway.  Doing what he suggested is certainly one way to accomplish it, but it's important to remember that you should always be testing *interfaces*, not implementations.  I'd need to know more about the actual work done in the closure, but usually when I see code like this, the closure encompasses implementation and isn't part of any interface (hence, does not need to be tested).

Answer (score 19):

If you want to mock an anonymous function (callback) you can mock a class with `__invoke` method. For example:

```
$shouldBeCalled = $this->getMock(\stdClass::class, ['__invoke']);
$shouldBeCalled->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__invoke');

$someServiceYouAreTesting->testedMethod($shouldBeCalled);
```

If you are using latest PHPUnit, you would have to use mock builder to do the trick:

```
$shouldBeCalled = $this->getMockBuilder(\stdClass::class)
    ->setMethods(['__invoke'])
    ->getMock();

$shouldBeCalled->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__invoke');

$someServiceYouAreTesting->testedMethod($shouldBeCalled);
```

You can also set expectations for method arguments or set a returning value, just the same way you would do it for any other method:

```
$shouldBeCalled->expects($this->once())
    ->method('__invoke')
    ->with($this->equalTo(5))
    ->willReturn(15);
```

Comment: great answer! I've wanted to know how to do this for a while now.

Comment: Not only does this work, but `is_callable($shouldBeCalled)` returns `true` as well.

Comment: Clever! It does not work for callback that take references, though.

Answer (score 9):

If the closure has some side effects inside `SUT` that could be verified by the test after the mock invocation, use `returnCallback` to provide another closure to be called with the passed arguments and have its return value returned to `SUT`. This will allow you to call `SUT`'s closure to cause the side effects.

```
 class SUT {
     public function foo($bar) {
         $someFunction = function() { return 5 * 3; };
         return $bar->baz($someFunction);
     }
 }

 class SUTTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
     public function testFoo() {
         $mockBar = $this->getMockBuilder('Bar')
              ->setMethods(array('baz'))
              ->getMock();
         $mockBar->expects($this->once())
              ->method('baz')
              ->will($this->returnCallback(function ($someFunction) {
                  return $someFunction();
              }));

         $sut = new SUT();

         self::assertEquals(15, $sut->foo($mockBar));
     }
 }
```