# PHPUnit how to test callbacks

Tags: mocking, phpunit

The first method will initiate a Closure call if it is an instance of Closure and it will pass the parameters and the second method `resolveByType` will format the output.

How can i test this correctly in PHPUnit ?

```
class Resolver
{

    public function initiate($table)
    {
        if($table->action instanceof \Closure) {

            $return =  call_user_func_array($table->action, $table->params);

            return $this->resolveByType($return);
        }
    }

     /**
     * resolve by returned type 
     *  
     * @param  mixed $data
     * @return void
     */
    public function resolveByType($data)
    {
        switch (gettype($data)) { 

            case 'array':  echo json_encode($data); break;
            case 'object': echo json_encode($data); break;
            default: echo $data; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPUnit testing with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255171/phpunit-testing-with-closures)

Comment: What would constitute a correct test for you in Phpunit, you have not said in your question. To unit-test `resolveByType` I would make use of a data provider and an output expectation but in the end I would then refactor to return values and do assertions on those instead of the output.