# How do i test a method of class that execute an method with an anonymous function as arguments?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

For specific needs, i have to test `Kernel` class in symfony 4.4 project and all is fine except method below `registerContainerConfiguration()`. It contains only one method that takes an argument as an `Anonymous function`, how could i test it entirely ? I can't find a way to get in it.

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $loader->load(function (ContainerBuilder $container) use ($loader) {
        $container->loadFromExtension('framework', [
            'router' => [
                'resource' => 'kernel::loadRoutes',
                'type' => 'service',
            ],
        ]);

        if (!$container->hasDefinition('kernel')) {
            $container->register('kernel', static::class)
                ->setSynthetic(true)
                ->setPublic(true)
            ;
        }

        $kernelDefinition = $container->getDefinition('kernel');
        $kernelDefinition->addTag('routing.route_loader');

        if ($this instanceof EventSubscriberInterface) {
            $kernelDefinition->addTag('kernel.event_subscriber');
        }

        $this->configureContainer($container, $loader);

        $container->addObjectResource($this);
    });
}
```

The code i already wrote:

```
public function testRegisterContainerConfiguration(): void
{
    $loader = $this->prophesize(LoaderInterface::class);

    $loader->load()
        ->shouldBeCalledOnce() // here i'm stuck
    ;

    $this->kernel->registerContainerConfiguration($loader->reveal());
}
```

PS: i tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255171/phpunit-testing-with-closures) but it seems to only mock anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to create real loader class inside test directory for tests purpose for example:

```
class LoaderMockObject implements LoaderInterface {
    //...

    public function __construct(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder)
    {
        $this->containerBuilder = $containerBuilder;
    }

    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        return $resource($this->containerBuilder);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can easily test the `containerBuilder` behaviour in this way:

```
public function testRegisterContainerConfiguration()
    {
        $containerBuilder = $this->createMock(ContainerBuilder::class);

        $containerBuilder->expects($this->once())
            ->method('loadFromExtension')
            ->withAnyParameters();

        // other expectations

        $loaderMock = new LoaderMockObject($containerBuilder);
        $kernel = new Kernel('test', false);

        $kernel->registerContainerConfiguration($loaderMock);
 }
```